# Logs are not generated in File

Tags: grails, logging, groovy, logback

I am using the logback in the my grails application and code for logback.groovy is as follows:-

```
def targetDir = BuildSettings.TARGET_DIR
if (Environment.isDevelopmentMode() && targetDir != null) 
{
    appender("FULL_STACKTRACE", FileAppender) {
       file = "${targetDir}/stacktrace.log"
       append = true
       encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
          pattern = "%level %logger - %msg%n"
       }
    }
    logger("StackTrace", DEBUG, ['FULL_STACKTRACE'], false)
}
root(ERROR, ['STDOUT'])
```

I have restarted my app but logs are not getting generated in stacktrace.log file.

Also can you please let me know why we need 2 loggers (root and logger). Can't we have logback.groovy without root.

Thanks,

Comment: print `targetDir` out and see what it looks like. Are you running in `development` mode?

Comment: Yes it's in development mode. Empty stacktrace.log file is already there but logs messages are not generated in it.

Answer (score 0):

Logback allows you to combine different loggers for different log files and packages.

For example:

```
appender('STDOUT', ConsoleAppender) {
    ...
}
appender('FILE', RollingFileAppender) {
    file = "${basePath}/logs/myLog.log"
    ...
}

root WARN, ['STDOUT', 'FILE']
logger 'org.hibernate.SQL', TRACE, ['STDOUT']
```

in this example your root logger will write logs (with level equal or higher then WARN) to console and log file.
but you will also receive TRACE or higher level logs to console from  org.hibernate.SQL package.

Logback is extrimely flexible. You can find manuals here https://logback.qos.ch/manual